# Connecting to MongoDB on AWS Instance via PHP returns timeout error

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just installed and configured MongoDB on an AWS Linux instance and I'm struggling to connect to it remotely using PHP and the `MongoClient` class, despite scrupulous checks on the configuration.

I have the `mongod` process running in the background, with the following configuration:

```
# mongod.conf

logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
logappend=true
fork=true
port=27017
dbpath=/srv/mongodb/
pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# bind_ip=127.0.0.1
bind_ip=0.0.0.0
```

I have my AWS Security Group set like so:

```
Custom TCP Rule   TCP   27017   [IP of php server]/32
```

And then my PHP script, which looks like this:

```
##### TESTING & DEBUG #####
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Display the status of the mongo extension
echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";

// Create the connection
$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com");

// Select the test database
$db = $mongo->test;

// Select a collection
$c = $db->collection;

// Get the cursor
$cursor = $c->find();

// Dump the contents of the cursor
echo '<pre>'.print_r($cursor,true).'</pre>';
```

This, of course, is the error being returned by PHP:

`Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017: Connection timed out' in test-mongo.php:14 Stack trace: #0 test-mongo.php(14): MongoClient->__construct('mongodb://ec2-x...') #1 {main} thrown in test-mongo.php on line 14`

The `mongod` server process is running, as verified by `ps -A`:

```
23171 ?  00:00:01 mongod
```

Any ideas what would cause it not to connect? Everything in the configuration seems right to me.

Comment: Some more info requested and some things to try: 1. check that you have that as an inbound rule, 2. check iptables (sudo iptables -L) for any blocking rules, 3. Just remove the bind_ip statement (defaults to binding to all) - it should work as is but just in case, 4. can you connect to port 27017 manually from that PHP host (with the mongo shell or even telnet)? 5. can you connect using the mongo shell from the local host itself?

Comment: The security group is inbound, I removed the bind_ip line altogether. iptables -L didn't show anything useful. My PHP server is 32-bit and I can't seem to run the mongo shell client on it. In #4, telnet times out trying to connect to the host _without_ even specifying the port. Trying the port with it produces a `Unknown host` error. I _can_ connect to the mongo shell locally on the mongo server.

Comment: I think you might be specifying the telnet arguments wrong.  If the ip was 192.168.1.1 then the command would be `telnet 192.168.1.1 27017` (no colon - if you add a colon it tries to resolve the whole thing as a hostname).  In any case, it sounds very much like you might have the wrong source ip for the PHP host in your security group, try running `curl ipecho.net/plain; echo` to verify